# Swift UI ListView doesn't appear until I transition a second time

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have set up a `NavigationLink` trough a button that takes me to a new view that needs to show a `ListView`, but it only appears after I go back to the original view and I push the button to transition again. What could be causing it.

```swift
List(vouchers){voucher in
    let i = vouchers.firstIndex(where: {$0 === voucher
    })
    VStack{
        Text("Voucher № \(i!+1) from \(voucher.activationDate!)")
                        .font(.system(size: 15))
        Divider()
        HStack{
        Text("Nominal Amount")
        Spacer()
        Text(String(format: voucher.currencyFormat, Float(voucher.points)/Float(voucher.currencyDivider)))
    }
    HStack{
        Text("Balance")
        Spacer()
        Text(String(format: voucher.currencyFormat, Float(voucher.pointsBalance)/Float(voucher.currencyDivider)))
    }
    HStack{
        Text("Activated on (UTC)")
        Spacer()
        Text("\(voucher.activationDate!)")
                             .font(.system(size: 15))
                     
    }
    HStack{
        Text("Valid to (UTC)")
        Spacer()
        Text("\(voucher.dateExpired!)")
        }
                    
    }
}
.refreshable{
    vm.getVouchersInfo(idToken: LoginManager.shared.idToken)
}
.onAppear() {
    UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    UITableViewCell.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
}
```

Comment: How is your `vouchers` collection populated? Might it be possible that the first time you come to your list view, that array is empty?

Comment: I am sure it's not empty because I populate it in the original view, just before the transition

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This needs a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).